# MFP8 Adapter Response compression

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Using MFP8 now, Earlier version was having compressResponse true for adapter. how to use that in MFP 8 ?

Am getting huge JSON object for a particular webservice, I need to know the size of the JSON in KB within adapter before returning to client side.

Answer (score 0):

Compression on adapter response is available in MFP 8.0 as well and is enabled by default.
The default adapter response compression threshold is 20480 bytes ( 20 KB).

To configure the value, in the MobileFirst Operations Console, navigate to `Runtime Settings -> Runtime Properties -> GZIP compression threshold for adapter responses`.

Edit the default value to configure your own threshold.